# TK-"Canvas" like widget that renders shapes

Tags: gtk

I want to draw some objects in my Gtk+ application, and let the user interact with them. I know about draw (expose) events and cairo drawing, and have used that before, but now I'm looking for something more like QGraphicsView + QGraphicsScene in QT, or the TK canvas (not HTML canvas!).

The difference is that you don't draw stuff on event, but you tell the widget what objects there are, and it draws them for you. Also it provides *z*-ordering, and hit-testing for user interaction.

I'm pretty sure such a widget exists for Gtk+, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: afaik there is no such widget in plain Gtk+. Sounds like you are looking for something like a scene graph library ... maybe check out [papyrus](http://libpapyrus.sourceforge.net), although actually that is based on gtkmm (Gtk+ C++ wrapper).

Comment: @MarkkuK.: Thanks, exactly. Papyrus is interesting, but I'm not sure it is maintained (last news is from 2010).

Comment: Good point, it was a shot in the dark. Here's another one: [clutter](http://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/). Good luck, please post something here if you find something that works.

Comment: @MarkkuK. According to Clutter's README, it's being replaced by Gtk 4: see [Clutter's repo on GitHub](https://github.com/GNOME/clutter). Just putting that out there for anyone who comes across this question in the future.